# Showing that $\|T\| = \sup\{\|Tx\| : \|x\| \leq 1 \} = \sup\{\|Tx\| : \|x\| = 1 \}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

**Exercise :**

> Let $T$ be a bounded linear operator such that $T : X \to Y$. Show that :
>   $$\|T\|  = \sup\{\|Tx\| : \|x\| \leq 1 \} $$
>   $$\quad\quad  = \sup\{\|Tx\| : \|x\| = 1 \}$$

**Attempt :**

First of all, we know that the operator norm is defined as :

$$\|T\| = \sup\bigg\{\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|} : x \in X, \forall x \neq 0\bigg\}$$

Since the operator $T$ is bounded, it holds that : $\|Tx\| \leq \|T\|\cdot \|x\|$ .

Thus, for the first set we can see that it it is : $\|Tx \| \leq \|T\| \cdot \|x\|$, where $\|x\| \leq 1$ and for the second set, it simply is : $\|Tx \| \leq \|T\|$. Thus, as sets, it is :

$$\sup\{\|Tx\| : \|x\| = 1 \} \leq \sup\{\|Tx\| : \|x\| \leq 1 \}$$

But, it is :

$$\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|} = \bigg\|\frac{Tx}{\|x\|}\bigg\| = \bigg\|T\bigg(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\bigg)\bigg\| \leq\|T\|\cdot \bigg\|\frac{x}{\|x\|}\bigg\| = \|T\|$$

Thus, it is : $\sup\bigg\{\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|} : x \in X, \forall x \neq 0\bigg\} \leq \sup\{\|Tx\| : \|x\| = 1 \}$.

Finally, if $\|x\| \leq 1$, it would be :

$$\|Tx\| \leq \frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}$$

Τhus it is : $\sup\{\|Tx\| : \|x\| \leq 1 \}  \leq \sup\bigg\{\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|} : x \in X, \forall x \neq 0\bigg\} $.

But, this leads to :

$$\boxed{\|T\| = \sup\bigg\{\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|} : x \in X, \forall x \neq 0\bigg\} = \sup\{\|Tx\| : \|x\| \leq 1 \} = \sup\{\|Tx\| : \|x\| = 1 \}}$$

**Question :** Is my approach rigorous enough and correct ?

Comment: You seem to have proved that $A\le C$, $B\le C$ and $A\le B$ and said this proves that $A=B=C$ which doesn't follow. You have $A\le B \le C$ and need $C\le A$

Comment: more simple than that: $\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}=\|T\frac{x}{\|x\|}\|$, and $\|\frac{x}{\|x\|}\|=1$

Comment: @user160738 What you denote as $A,B,C$ as fas as my sets are concerned ? What am I missing and any tips on proving ?

Comment: @Masacroso Used that in my proof, but how would I be able to yield something more simply ? I'm probably not seeing it.

Comment: @Rebellos $\sup\{x/\|x\|:x\in X\land x\neq 0\}=\sup\{x\in X:\|x\|=1\}$

Comment: @Masacroso It is $\|Tx\|/\|x\|$ and not $x/\|x\|$.

Comment: @Rebellos I know, check my first comment to complete the proof. The supremum is taken from the same set of points!!!, that is $$\{x/\|x\|:x\in X\land x\neq 0\}=\{x\in X:\|x\|=1\}$$

Comment: You need to assume $X\ne\{0\}$, otherwise the set in the second sup is void.

Comment: I checked it again, the proof is correct as it makes a cycle all over. @daw Yes, correctly, it should be $X \neq \{0\}$ but that should probably be initially stated in the exercise.