# Motivation for norm of linear operator $T:E \rightarrow F$ defined for $\|x\|_E \leq 1$?

Tags: operator-theory

Motivation for norm of linear operator $T:E \rightarrow F$ defined for $\|x\|_E \leq 1$?

Initial guess: standardization/normalization. I.e. this gives the "unit measure" of the norm.

See def. here:

[Showing that $\|T\| = \sup\{\|Tx\| : \|x\| \leq 1 \} = \sup\{\|Tx\| : \|x\| = 1 \}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982673/showing-that-t-sup-tx-x-leq-1-sup-tx-x-1)

Comment: Otherwise the "norm" would be either zero or infinity (if you allow all $x$), which is not very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that there is $C>0$ s.t. $$\|Tx\|_{F}\leq C\|x\|_E.$$
In particular, if $\|x\|_E\neq 0$, then $$\frac{\|Tx\|_{F}}{\|x\|_E}\leq C,$$
i.e. $$\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Tx\|_F}{\|x\|_E}\leq C<\infty .$$

We therefore define $\|T\|$ by the smallest $C$ s.t. $$\|Tx\|_F\leq C\|x\|_E,$$
for all $x\in E$, or equivalently as $$\|T\|:=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Tx\|_F}{\|x\|_E}.$$

I let you show that it's indeed a norm. In fact, since $T$ is linear, $$\frac{1}{\|x\|_E}T(x)=T\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|_E}\right),$$
and thus $$\frac{\|Tx\|_F}{\|x\|_E}= \left\|T\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)\right\|_F=\|T(y)\|_F,$$
where $\|y\|_E=1$. Therefore, we have that $$\|T\|=\sup_{\|y\|_E=1}\|T(y)\|_F,$$

and thus, $$\|T\|\leq \sup_{\|x\|_E\leq 1}\|Tx\|_{F}.$$

I let you prove (as an exercise) that the inverse inequality holds as well.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why we don't define
$$ \Vert T \Vert_\infty = \sup_{x\in E} \Vert Tx \Vert_F $$
is that this quantity is either zero or $+\infty$. Indeed, if $T$ is not equal to the zero function, then there exists $x_0$ such that $Tx_0 \neq 0$. However, then we get
$$ \Vert T \Vert_\infty \geq \sup_{t\in \mathbb{R}} \Vert T(tx_0)\Vert_F = \sup_{t\in \mathbb{R}} \vert t \vert \cdot \Vert Tx_0 \Vert_F = + \infty. $$
Of course we could define
$$ \Vert T \Vert_C = \sup_{x\in E: \ \Vert x \Vert_E \leq C} \Vert Tx \Vert_F $$
for your favourite $C>0$ but this is essentially the same thing as the usual definition of the norm as we have
$$\Vert T \Vert_C =  \sup_{x\in E: \ \Vert x \Vert_E \leq C} \Vert Tx \Vert_F = \sup_{x\in E: \ \Vert x \Vert_E \leq 1} \Vert T(Cx) \Vert_F = C \Vert T \Vert $$